incompatibility in formatting table
--Hello,
i try to generate a table like the picture (see attachment) but i can't do it correctly and it seems some bugs occured due to incompatibility between \hhline and \multirow.
below my code:
    \definecolor{SGblue}{RGB}{0, 164, 196}
{
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X[3,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|}
\rowcolor{SGblue}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
{} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{DIFFERENCIATED STAGE}} \\
\hhline{ ------------}
\rowcolor{SGblue}
%{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c!{\color{white}\vline}}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ECTODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c!{\color{white}\vline}}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{MESODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ENDODERM}}\\
{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ECTODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{MESODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ENDODERM}} \\
\rowcolor{SGblue}
\hhline{ ------------}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor{white}{\bf\textcolor{white}{\rule{0pt}{1em}Samples name\rule[-1em]{0pt}{1em}}}} & \bf\textcolor{white}{EN1} & \bf\textcolor{white}{MAP2} &  \bf\textcolor{white}{NEFL} & \bf\textcolor{white}{PAX6} & \bf\textcolor{white}{AFP} &
\bf\textcolor{white}{FOXA2} & \bf\textcolor{white}{SOX17} & \bf\textcolor{white}{SST} & \bf\textcolor{white}{CDH5} & \bf\textcolor{white}{HAND1} & \bf\textcolor{white}{MYOG} & \bf\textcolor{white}{TBXT} \\
\arrayrulecolor{SGblue}
\textbf{EB14} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} \\
\hline
\textbf{HF11} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\textbf{\large{(NS)}} indicates non-significant expression, \textbf{\large{(+)}} represents overexpression, and \textbf{\large{(-)}} denotes underexpression.}  \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
}



Please never jut post sniplets like this. Post full but minimal examples that others can copy and test as is. Note that tabu is known to have issues and is not maintained anymore. Additionally \bf has been maked as don't use since 1993! Is this code from some autogen tool?

Rather than try to slavishly reproduce a rather gaudy-looking table template, I'd focus on coming up with a clean-looking, easy-to-read and easy-to-understand layout of my own.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{booktabs}
\let\fns\footnotesize % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn space

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{c} }
\toprule
Samples  & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Differentiated Stage} \\
\cmidrule{2-13}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Ectoderm}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Mesoderm}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Endoderm} \\
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13}
& \fns EN1  & \fns MAP   & \fns NEFL  & \fns PAX6 
& \fns AFP  & \fns FOXA2 & \fns SOX17 & \fns SST
& \fns CDH5 & \fns HAND1 & \fns MYOG  & \fns TBXT \\
\midrule
EB14 & $+$ & NS & $+$ & $+$ & $+$ & $+$ & $+$ & NS & $+$ & $+$ & $+$ & $+$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip\fns
(NS), ($+$), and ($-$) represent non-significant expression, overexpression, and underexpression, resp.

\end{table}

\end{document}


yes, nice but but the word 'sample' is not centered on the 3 rows, and rowcolors/linecolors are missing.

@LaurentMANCHON - Unless you are forced to reproduce the god-awful, childish-looking color scheme, I'd stay far away from it. FWIW, I deliberately placed "Samples" in the top row as I believe it's of the same importance as "Differentiated Stage". However, if you must place "Samples" further down, I suggest you move it from its current location down to the next row, i.e., to just in front of & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Ectoderm}.

If you actually want a tabular with the design you suggest, here is a way with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\noindent
\sffamily
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.7pt}%
\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{12}{|[color=white]X[c]}|}[rules/color=cyan]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=3,color=white,rowcolor=cyan]{}
\Block{3-1}{Samples} & \Block{1-*}{DIFFERENCIATED STAGE} \\
\Hline[color=white]
& \Block{1-4}{ECTODERM} &&&& \Block{1-4}{MESODERM} &&&& \Block{1-4}{ENDODERM}  \\
\Hline[color=white]
& EN1 & MAP2 & NEFL & PAX6 & AFP & FOXA2 & SOX17 & SST & CDH5 & HAND1 & MYOG & TBXT \\
\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}
EB14 & + & NS & + & + & + & + & + & NS & + & + & + & + \\
\Block{1-*}{(NS) indicates non-significant expression, (+) represents
  overexpression, and (-) denotes underexpression} 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



--Hi, yes, nicematrix gives the result I'm looking for.
but the word 'sample' is not centered on the 3 lines and the white horizontal line should only appear on the last 12 columns (as shown in the image). thank you

That question was cross-posted to LaTeX.org; I already posted an answer there: the error (Misplaced \omit) disappears when you put the \rowcolor command after the \hhline command instead of before it. Full MWE with your code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline,tabu,multirow}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{SGblue}{RGB}{0, 164, 196}
{
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X[3,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|X[1,c,m]|}
\rowcolor{SGblue}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
{} & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{DIFFERENCIATED STAGE}} \\
\hhline{ ------------}
\rowcolor{SGblue}
%{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c!{\color{white}\vline}}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ECTODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c!{\color{white}\vline}}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{MESODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ENDODERM}}\\
{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ECTODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{MESODERM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\large\bf\textcolor{white}{ENDODERM}} \\
\hhline{ ------------}
\rowcolor{SGblue}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textcolor{white}{\bf\textcolor{white}{\rule{0pt}{1em}Samples name\rule[-1em]{0pt}{1em}}}} & \bf\textcolor{white}{EN1} & \bf\textcolor{white}{MAP2} &  \bf\textcolor{white}{NEFL} & \bf\textcolor{white}{PAX6} & \bf\textcolor{white}{AFP} &
\bf\textcolor{white}{FOXA2} & \bf\textcolor{white}{SOX17} & \bf\textcolor{white}{SST} & \bf\textcolor{white}{CDH5} & \bf\textcolor{white}{HAND1} & \bf\textcolor{white}{MYOG} & \bf\textcolor{white}{TBXT} \\
\arrayrulecolor{SGblue}
\textbf{EB14} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} \\
\hline
\textbf{HF11} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{NS} & \large\textbf{+} & \large\textbf{+} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{13}{|c|}{\textbf{\large{(NS)}} indicates non-significant expression, \textbf{\large{(+)}} represents overexpression, and \textbf{\large{(-)}} denotes underexpression.}  \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}


A solution with tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{SGblue}{RGB}{0, 164, 196}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={c*{12}{X[c]}},
    columns={font={\footnotesize}},
    hlines={SGblue,wd=0.8pt},
    vlines={SGblue,wd=0.8pt},
    colsep=1pt,
    row{1-2}={SGblue, fg=white,font={\footnotesize\bfseries}},
    row{3}={SGblue, fg=white, font={\tiny\bfseries}},
    cell{4}{1}={font={\footnotesize\bfseries}},
    hline{2,3}={white},
    vline{2-Y}={1-3}{white},
    }
\SetCell[r=3]{c}Samples & \SetCell[c=12]{c}DIFFERENCIATED STAGE &&&&&&&&&&\\
& \SetCell[c=4]{c}ECTODERM &&&& \SetCell[c=4]{c}MESODERM &&&& \SetCell[c=4]{c}ENDODERM &&& \\
& EN1 & MAP2 & NEFL & PAX6 & AFP & FOXA2 & SOX17 & SST & CDH5 & HAND1 & MYOG & TBXT \\
EB14 & + & NS & + & + & + & + & + & NS & + & + & + & + \\
\SetCell[c=13]{c}\textbf{(NS)} indicates non-significant expression, (+) represents
  overexpression, and (-) denotes underexpression\\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


